# motd not showing up on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10

Upon login I get a prompt and none of the stuff from `/etc/update-motd.d`

Version `Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-30-generic x86_64)`

If I run `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` I get the expected output - it just doesn't run automatically upon login.

I don't have `$HOME/.hushlogin` configured at all.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you logging in? GUI, terminal emulator, `bash --login`, `agetty`, serial terminal or what? Read `man bash` about Startup Files  read the startup files to see which one does the `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` and under what  conditions.

Comment: ... it's done via PAM these days I think (`/etc/pam.d/login` for local sessions or `/etc/pam.d/sshd` for remote sessions)

Comment: @waltinator I'm logging in via SSH to the terminal, no GUI.

Comment: @steeldriver: I see that the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file contains the `session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic` which doesn't exist on my system. I'll chase that down - thanks for the heads up!!

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver that worked. I needed to amend the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow PAM to be triggered. Thanks for the hint!!

Comment: @salvo please consider turning your findings into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

The file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` needed to be set this line `UsePAM yes`. That allowed the interactive login to trigger the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd` that contained `session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic` to run, which in turn ran the files in `/etc/update-motd.d/` to trigger my MOTD when I login.

Comment: Following the steps of the solution, I found the file "/run/motd.dynamic" did not exist, but "/run/motd.dynamic.new" did. I copied the "new" file to the expected name and it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: the rename that @TedH. mentioned was also the solution for me. may you can edit the answer with this "additional step"? it could help :)